# Create icon for java application as in skype

Tags: java, swing, awt

Skype icon is little and hides on the bottom left corner of my desktop near the clock. Can I create something like this of my own application on java with Swing or Abstract Window Toolkit?

Comment: show me a picture to help you... Of course you can do it with java.

Comment: To be clear - are you asking if Java allows you to minimize a program to the taskbar?

Comment: yes i ask if Java allows you to minimize a program to the taskbar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the SystemTray class introduced in Java 6.

The essential steps are:

```
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    final TrayIcon trayIcon =
            new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // Populate popup menu

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

Comment: but my application is jframe not popmenu can i do with jframe?

Comment: @eriksson Read the tutorial he linked to ... of course you can